# Incorrect Type In MainActivity

Tags: android, button, webview

I'm making a webView browser and I'm trying to make a button that slides down to show more buttons, I've shown the code where the errors occur below, I've also stated on what lines the errors occur on. Thanks in advance!

```
ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView(); *<-The method*             -   *getExpandableListView() is undefined for the type MainActivity IS THE ERROR I GET ON  -   THAT LINE*
(ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list)

expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
expandableList.setClickable(true);

setGroupParents();
setChildData();

MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems,childItems);

adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE),  -   this);
expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this); *<-The method                                 -   setOnChildClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener) in the type            -   ExpandableListView is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity) IS THE ERROR I   -   GET ON THAT LINE*
}
```

Comment: What does your `Activity` extend?

Comment: MainActivity extends Activity? I'm a little confused by that comment, sorry

Comment: See my answer. I think that is the problem. I can try to elaborate if you need.

Comment: All good, thanks a lot! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `ExpandableListView` but I'm sure its like `ListView` in that if you aren't extending `ExpandableListActivity` then you will get that error.

You need to either create your own `View` in your `layout` that is an `ExpandableListView` or you need to `extends ExpandableListView` in your `Activity` to use its methods and listeners in this way such as `getExpandableListView()`

Comment: Thanks guys! Got it sussed out, great answers :)

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity has to extend ExpandableListActivity. I suspect you've just used an Activity. You'll have to provide the line that declares your Activity.

expandableList.setOnChildClickListener() takes an argument of type ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener. In the code you've presented, I don't see that you've instantiated a Listener. If your activity declaration also declares that you implement the ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener interface, I don't see the override for onChildClic().

In short, you should have

```
public class MainActivity extends 
    ExpandableListActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int 
            groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```